# "Error: identifier expected" ao tentar compilar um projeto com vídeos em res/raw

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo somente pra gerenciar vídeos que já estão dentro do aplicativo dentro da pasta res/raw, mas quando vou compilar sem chamar os vídeos, dá os erros:

> Error: identifier expected

e

> Error: illegal start of type

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Importante também informar qual o erro apresentado no *logcat*, assim teremos um direcionamento maior para encontrar a solução.

Comment: Esta aí, desculpem a demora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que os nomes dos seus arquivos começam com número.

Como o SDK do Android usa os nomes dos arquivos para criar variáveis correspondentes no arquivo `R.java`, se você usar um nome que não seja um [identificador Java válido](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbuk/index.html), o `R.java` não compila. O mesmo vale para imagens.

Tente trocar os nomes dos vídeos para, por exemplo, `video_1.mp4`, `video_2.mp4` etc.

Comment: Realmente era esse o erro, obrigado, está resolvido :D